# Is it wise to use a pointer to access values in an std::map

Tags: c++, pointers, stdmap

Is it dangerous to returning a pointer out of a `std::map::find` to the data and using that as opposed to getting a copy of the data?

Currently, i get a pointer to an entry in my map and pass it to another function to display the data. I'm concerned about items moving causing the pointer to become invalid. Is this a legit concern?

Here is my sample function:

```
MyStruct* StructManagementClass::GetStructPtr(int structId)

{
    std::map<int, MyStruct>::iterator foundStruct;
    foundStruct= myStructList.find(structId);
    if (foundStruct== myStructList.end())
    {
        MyStruct newStruct;
        memset(&newStruct, 0, sizeof(MyStruct));
        myStructList.structId= structId;
        myStructList.insert(pair<int, MyStruct>(structId, newStruct));

       foundStruct= myStructList.find(structId);
   }

   return (MyStruct*) &foundStruct->second;
```

}

Comment: I think you mean iterators instead of pointers?

Comment: Can you please show some code? By "returning a pointer out of a map.find" do you mean the iterator? The iterator would be valid until the function which called .find() exits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would undoubtedly be more typical to return an iterator than a pointer, though it probably makes little difference.

As far as remaining valid goes: a map iterator remains valid until/unless the item it refers to is removed/erased from the map.

When you insert or delete some *other* node in the map, that can result in the nodes in the map being rearranged. That's done by manipulating the pointers between the nodes though, so it changes what other nodes contain pointers to the node you care about, but does not change the address or content of that particular node, so pointers/iterators to that node remain valid.

Comment: Does adding/removing other elements to the map affect the arithmetic on that iterator?

Comment: @nims: No -- unless the item it refers to is removed from the map, the iterator remains valid so you can use it just like any other iterator (well, any other iterator into a map, anyway).

Comment: It looks like in my sample, i am returning a pointer to the iterator->second, and not actually the map[key]->second.  is that the case?

Comment: @Jason: Yes, that looks about right. I should add, however, that the code doesn't look very good to me -- between a cast that should be unnecessary, using `memset`, and the whole thing being roughly equivalent to `return your_map.insert(...).second;` it just doesn't jump off the page as really clean code.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to be the cleanest code.  I'm new to stl so i'm constantly reworking it as a learn more.  
I mentioned below that the cast wasn't there in the first place, but i was trying to track down a bug.

What is the problem with memset?  I have fields that won't all be populated and i know that they do not get initialized to 0, which is the value i need them to be if not used.

Comment: @Jason: Initializing that structure should be done in its constructor.

Comment: If i return a copy of the std:map->second (instead of a pointer), is it acceptable to return myListStruct[structId]? This assumes that the key actually exists (i would verify that it exists before attempting to return).

Answer (score 3):

As long as you, your code, and your development team understand the lifetime of std::map values ( valid after `insert`, and invalid after `erase`, `clear`, `assign`, or `operator=` ), then using an `iterator`, `const_iterator`, `::mapped_type*`, or `::mapped_type const*` are all valid.  Also, if the return is always guaranteed to exist, then `::mapped_type&`, or `::mapped_type const&` are also valid.

As for wise, I'd prefer the `const` versions over the mutable versions, and I'd prefer references over pointers over iterators.

Returning an iterator vs. a pointer is bad:

- it exposes an implementation detail.
- it is awkward to use, as the caller has to know to dereference the iterator, that the result is an std::pair, and that one must then call `.second` to get the actual value.

  - `.first` is the key that the user may not care about.
- determining if an iterator is invalid requires knowledge of `::end()`, which is not obviously available to the caller.

Answer (score 2):

It's not dangerous - the pointer remains valid just as long as an iterator or a reference does.

However, in your particular case, I would argue that it is not the right thing anyway. Your function unconditionally returns a result. It never returns null. So why not return a reference?

Also, some comments on your code.

```
std::map<int, MyStruct>::iterator foundStruct;
foundStruct = myStructList.find(structId);
```

Why not combine declaration and assignment into initialization? Then, if you have C++11 support, you can just write

```
auto foundStruct = myStructList.find(structId);
```

Then:

```
  myStructList.insert(pair<int, MyStruct>(structId, newStruct));
  foundStruct = myStructList.find(structId);
```

You can simplify the insertion using make_pair. You can also avoid the redundant lookup, because insert returns an iterator to the newly inserted element (as the first element of a pair).

```
  foundStruct = myStructList.insert(make_pair(structId, newStruct)).first;
```

Finally:

```
return (MyStruct*) &foundStruct->second;
```

Don't ever use C-style casts. It might not do what you expect. Also, don't use casts at all when they're not necessary. &foundStruct->second already has type MyStruct*, so why insert a cast? The only thing it does is hide a place that you need to change if you ever, say, change the value type of your map.

Comment: The cast was a debugging thing i was working through.  It was not there originally.  I'll take it out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

If you build a generic function without knowing the use of it, it can be dangerous to return the pointer (or the iterator) since it can become un-valid.

I would advice do one of two:
1. work with std::shared_ptr and return that. (see below)
2. return the struct by value (can be slower)

```
//change the difination of the list to
std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<MyStruct>>myStructList;

std::shared_ptr<MyStruct> StructManagementClass::GetStructPtr(int structId)
{
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<MyStruct>>::iterator foundStruct;
    foundStruct = myStructList.find(structId);
    if (foundStruct == myStructList.end())
    {
        MyStruct newStruct;
        memset(&newStruct, 0, sizeof(MyStruct));
        myStructList.structId= structId;
        myStructList.insert(pair<int, shared_ptr<MyStruct>>(structId, shared_ptr<MyStruct>(newStruct)));

       foundStruct= myStructList.find(structId);
   }

   return foundStruct->second;
```